# Обработка нескольких форм для однй модели на backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Здравствуйте. Вопрос касается организации моделей backbone на клиенте

На сервере есть модель пользователя, которая содержит в себе разного рода поля:

- **Персональная информация**

  - Имя
  - Фамилия
  - Дата рождения
- **Прочая информация**

  - Обо мне (текст)
  - Интересы (текст)

На странице это всё разбивается на две формы - форма персональной информации и форма прочей информации. Соответственно api было написано так, чтобы на каждую форму были загрузка и сохранение только тех полей, которые есть в этой форме. Методы соответственно GET и PUT.

Ну и назрел вопрос с backbon'ом - как правильно организовать модели? В моём случае я вижу следующее разделение - на каждую форму объявляю по модели, например UserPersonalModel и UserOtherModel, на каждую из них прибиваю url и пользуюсь.

Или же правильно было бы не разделять модели и написать одну UserModel, а сохранение разделить на разные части, вроде .savePersonal, .saveOther методов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта верны. При первом варианте вы сохраняете данные порционно. При втором все сразу. Накладные расходы минимальны что в первом, что во втором случае.

Лично я использую первый способ.